# SpringCloudGateway - configuration parameter IO_SELECT_COUNT

Tags: spring, netty, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

I'm using SpringCloudGateway, I have an doubt on config parameter `IO_SELECT_COUNT`

```
/**
 * Default selector thread count, fallback to -1 (no selector thread)
 */
public static final String IO_SELECT_COUNT = "reactor.netty.ioSelectCount";
```

Is this the thread count of netty boss eventloop group? why could this be -1 by default?

And is there any suggestion for the configuration of this parameter `IO_SELECT_COUNT` ?

Comment: It says right there in the comment. When -1 is set, there's no selector thread.

Comment: As i understand, there must be a boss thread in netty, why could it be -1?

Comment: When there is no `boss` (selector ELG) then one of the worker threads will be used for that purpose. You can measure your solution with/without this configuration and decide by yourself whether you need `boss` (selector ELG) or not.